# getting trouble with endless loop (python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

hey guys can some one help with this loop it is getting to the first if and get stuck 
appreciating your help

```
Options = int(input('Enter an Options :'))

while Options != 0:
    if Options == 1:
        item = input('enter the item : ')
        qnty = int(input('Enter the Quantitiy for the item : '))
        Shoping_list[item] = qnty

    elif Options == 2:
        for item in Shoping_list:
            print(item, ':', Shoping_list[item])
        item = input('Enter the item you want to Remove : ')
        del(Shoping_list[item])

    elif Options == 3:
        for item in Shoping_list:
            print(item, ':', Shoping_list[item])

    elif Options != 0:
        print('you didnt enter a valid number ')
else:
    print('shopping list is close')
```

Comment: Your `Options` will never change inside the loop.

Comment: `Options` is not changed inside loop, so there is no way for the condition to be false unless you initially entered a 0.

Comment: another thing is that `Shoping_list` isn't really defined, nor is it accessible within other scopes like shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit hard to read and hard to maintenance
I suggest, change the 'while loop' to loop infinitely when you want to exit, simply break the loop
and I prefer to show a menu before asking an option.

You can change your code like this:

```
def display_menu():
    print("1. Add a new item to shopping list")
    print("2. Remove an item")
    print("3. Print Shopping List Items")
    print("0. Exit")
    return int(input('Enter an Options (0~3):'))


while True:
    option = display_menu()

    if option == 1:
        item = input('enter the item : ')
        qnty = int(input('Enter the Quantitiy for the item : '))
        Shoping_list[item] = qnty

    elif option == 2:
        for item in Shoping_list:
            print(item, ':', Shoping_list[item])
        item = input('Enter the item you want to Remove : ')
        del(Shoping_list[item])

    elif option == 3:
        for item in Shoping_list:
            print(item, ':', Shoping_list[item])

    elif option == 0:
        print('shopping list is close')
        break      # Exit menu

    else:    
        print('you didnt enter a valid number ')
```

Answer (score 0):

In each of your if statements, insert Options = 0 at the end. Since your while loop depends on options not being 0. Resetting it to 0 allows the user to pick another option.

```
while Options != 0:
    if Options == 1:
        item = input('enter the item : ')
        qnty = int(input('Enter the Quantitiy for the item : '))
        Shoping_list[item] = qnty
        Options = 0
```

Also, as a tip, make sure your spelling and grammar are accurate, and that you are consistent with spacing. It makes it a lot easier for others to read your code.

Here's a working example of the correct if loops. The user can modify the dictionary with the if loops, and can run each of them one after another.

```
Shoping_list = {}
while True:
    Options = int(input('Enter an Options :'))

    while Options != 0:
        if Options == 1:
            item = input('enter the item : ')
            qnty = int(input('Enter the Quantitiy for the item : '))
            Shoping_list[item] = qnty
            Options = 0

        elif Options == 2:
            for item in Shoping_list:
                print(item, ':', Shoping_list[item])
            item = input('Enter the item you want to Remove : ')
            del(Shoping_list[item])
            Options = 0

        elif Options == 3:
            for item in Shoping_list:
                print(item, ':', Shoping_list[item])
            Options = 0

        elif Options != 0:
            print('you didnt enter a valid number ')

    else:
        print('shopping list is close')
```

Answer (score 0):

insert the first statement `Options = int(input('Enter an option'))` inside the while loop.

```
while options!=0:
  Options = int(input('Enter an option'))
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome thanks a lot guys ! Im new to python this info very helpful

```
def display_menu():
    print("1. Add a new item to shopping list")
    print("2. Remove an item")
    print("3. Print Shopping List Items")
    print("0. Exit")
    return int(input('Enter an Options (0~3):'))


while True:
    option = display_menu()

    if option == 1:
        item = input('enter the item : ')
        qnty = int(input('Enter the Quantitiy for the item : '))
        Shoping_list[item] = qnty

    elif option == 2:
        for item in Shoping_list:
            print(item, ':', Shoping_list[item])
        item = input('Enter the item you want to Remove : ')
        del(Shoping_list[item])

    elif option == 3:
        for item in Shoping_list:
            print(item, ':', Shoping_list[item])

    elif option == 0:
        print('shopping list is close')
        break      # Exit menu

    else:    
        print('you didnt enter a valid number ')
```

P.s like the option with the function you can call